# How to code nowadays?

Tags: php, git

I'm a PHP developer for some time nowand in the past few years i've seen a radical change in the style of coding(not necessarly PHP).

I've been struggling for the past year to get my head wrapped arround all the things and tools that i need to code more efficeint and faster, but i can't seem to make it. It's all kind of a mess in my head. How do i use git, composer, unit testing, libs, frameworks, etc(many more), all in perfect harmony with eachother? I need some kind of tutorials to get ahold of this principles. Does anyone know a complete tutorial, or atleast some tutorials about this things? I've tried searching and trying but none of them were what i needed.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Things are always in flux.  Learn new (and old!) technologies as you work on new projects.  Never stop learning.  Always be trying something new.  You have to build your experiences if you expect to use technology effectively.

Comment: Did you look at http://www.phptherightway.com/ yet? Seems to contain some of the tutoring you're looking for.

Comment: I think it's time for you to stop coding with vanilla PHP and pick up a framework of your choice. As far as git is concerned, GitHub has some [nice articles](https://help.github.com/categories/19/articles) in its help section.

Comment: @DaSourcerer Wut? OP is struggling with wrapping his head around everything and your "solution" is to add more "magic".

Comment: @PeeHaa absolutely. After all the "magic" is taking away a lot of complexity.

Comment: @DaSourcerer Sounds like a perfect recipe for a failed project to me.

Comment: Rather than starting to _use_ a framework, I would recommend (after reading http://phptherightway.com) would be to download a framework and start looking at how the code is structured.  [Symfony](http://symfony.com/) uses all the technologies you ask about, for example.

Comment: [nettuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/category/tutorials/php/) has some nice tutorials regarding OOP, unit testing and alike.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from though - if someone coded PHP in 2008 then looked at it again in late 2013 for the first time, it would scarcely be recognizable, and things have changed very much for the better.

Comment: @PeeHaa I don't agree. I think a framework will bring the structure and clarity OP is missing.

Answer (score 2):

[PHP the right way](http://www.phptherightway.com) tries to catalog many of the tools and techniques for modern PHP development. It's not perfect, but it's a good place to start.